# How to use KeyboardAvoidingView in full screen mode?

Tags: react-native, native-base

[image]

The above yellow colored area is `Textarea` and a panel of buttons expected to stick to bottom of screen all the time. However when user trying to type, Keyboard will block the view as shown below

[image]

I've implemented `KeyboardAvoidingView` but it failed to make the button appear above of keyboard.

My code is as below:

```
  <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <Container style={Styles.containerStyle}>
      <Textarea 
        autoCapitalize="none"
        autoCorrect={false}
        style={Styles.textAreaStyle}
      />
      <View style={Styles.buttonPanelStyle}>
        <Button style={Styles.buttonStyle}><Text>CANCEL</Text></Button>
        <Button style={Styles.buttonStyle}><Text>SAVE</Text></Button>
      </View>
    </Container>
  </KeyboardAvoidingView>


const Styles = StyleSheet.create({
  containerStyle: { backgroundColor: 'green' },
  textAreaStyle: { backgroundColor: 'yellow', flex: 1 },
  buttonPanelStyle: { backgroundColor: 'red', flexDirection: 'row' },
  buttonStyle: { flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center' }
});
```

Comment: Did you try to use a scrollview with flexGrow?

Comment: Generate a snack...

Comment: @RaajNadar: Please take a look at https://snack.expo.io/HyMPYDjR7

Comment: @SamithaNanayakkara: I'm not sure how to implement scrollview for my case as I'm not rendering a list of item but a Textarea component instead. If you may please take a look at my snack: https://snack.expo.io/HyMPYDjR7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a way to get around with it. Wrapped the `KeyboardAvoidingView` with an extra `View`, and implement `onLayout` to recalculate the height of screens. Sample code as below:

```js
const { height: fullHeight } = Dimensions.get('window');

onLayout = ({
  nativeEvent: { layout: { height } },
}) => {
  const offset = fullHeight - height;
  this.setState({ offset });
}

<View style={{ flex: 1 }} onLayout={this.onLayout}>
  <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" style={{ flex: 1 }} keyboardVerticalOffset={this.state.offset}>
    ...
  </KeyboardAvoidingView>
</View>
```